# IIS7 or ASP.NET is returning an odd client IP Address

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, iis-7

In my ASP.NET application, I'm saying something like this to get the client IP address:

```
string ipAddress = HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress;
```

This is the normal, straightforward way that I've always used, and it's always seemed to work.  Everybody knows that the above statement is just a wrapper for the REMOTE_ADDR server variable.

Simple enough, right?  Well, in the last few days I've been noticing that on my local dev machine, it's returning this as the value:

```
"fe80::dde4:def3:7f1b:a582%10"
```

I have no earthly idea why.  I'm running Vista x64 and running my app with IIS7.  I do have IPv4 and IPv6 enabled, but that usually returns something like:

```
"1::"
```

I have no idea why this is happening.  Rebooting solves nothing.

**EDIT:**

I'm using Chrome when this happens.

Comment: Running ifconfig /all, I see a very similar value on my network adapter for "Link-local IPv6 address".

Comment: @lfonlfonlfon - just delete the question if you don't want it anymore - deleting the contents is just stupid

Comment: I tried that first, Einstein.  You can't delete items that are flagged as accepted or have up votes.

Comment: Why would you want to delete the question? The whole point of SO is for these questions to be archived for future reference.

Comment: I have uncovered a number of highly undesirable things about the site and no longer want my content on it.

Comment: Then you must contact an admin, editing it does not delete it.

Comment: And by posting it to a public site, you have given up most rights to it.

Comment: I think it's because he lost half his rep in the latest voting fraud recalc

Answer (score 8):

It looks like it's returning [IPv6](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_v6).

`::1` is the loopback address for IPv6, which is simply the reversed byte order of `1::`.

I should also note that `fe80::/10` addresses in IPv6 are Autoconfiguration IP addresses (in IPv4, these are `169.254.0.0/16`). If for example you are on a private LAN and cannot access a DHCP server, Windows will automatically assign your ethernet adapter an autoconfiguration IP address.

Just FYI, You should generally assign a private IP address to adapters that are not able to reach a DHCP server.

Comment: Hmm, you're right.  I've never seen what IP6 looks like before.  I'll look into this.  Upvote for now for the info.

Answer (score 4):

Are you using FireFox when you see this issue? That by default will use IPv6 when available. I'd recommend turning that off:

- Navigate to "about:config"
- Find the "network.dns.disableIPv6" entry
- Set it to true

This will also speed up local development and debugging, as FF hangs sometimes for no apparent reason when IPv6 is enabled.

The other option I'd recommend is to just disable IPv6. It's not useful right now unless you're running IPv6 end-to-end, which no end user ISP's are. Just open connection properties on your connection and untick the "Internet Protocol Version 6 (TCP/IPv6)" box.

Comment: I'm using Chrome.  I'll see what happens with your suggestions.

Comment: I have the same configuration as PaulW, and testing with FF with IPv6 entry enabled, I get the IPv4 address in both properties.

Comment: Actually, I already had that set to true.  I was using Chrome anyway, but Firefox was returning IPv4.